# How to get install and uninstall stats from Google Developer Play store?

Tags: google-developers-console

Does google developer API provides install and uninstall information? I found one that provide reviews but I couldn't find anything related to install/uninstall. Is there any option to get install/uninstall information using API?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution using C#.

```
var storageService = new StorageService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                ApplicationName = "App Name",
                ApiKey = "APIKey goes here ",
            });

            var storage = StorageClient.Create();
            string localPath = "C:\\test\test.csv";
            using (var outputFile = File.OpenWrite(localPath))
            {
                storage.DownloadObject("gs://pubsite_prod_rev_23628868/stats/installs/", "installs", outputFile);
            }
```

---

ApiKey --> Create a google project and generate API Key

gs://pubsite_prod_rev_23628868/stats/installs/ --> You can get this path in your Google Developer Dashboard under Reports